# Checking the Sobolev norm

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to show that the Sobolev norm is indeed a norm. Why is the following statement true?

For $p \in [1, \infty)$,
$$
\left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le k}(||D^{\alpha}u||_{L^p(U)} + ||D^{\alpha}v||_{L^p(U)})^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \le \left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le k}||D^{\alpha}u||_{L^p(U)}^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} + \left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le k}||D^{\alpha}v||_{L^p(U)}^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Minkowski's Inequality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_Inequality_for_Sums) for sums.

Comment: ... and a typo in it: a dropped $p$-power on the left-hand side...